# Android: multiple views in one activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android, and I am working on a Quiz app with a set of questions, each question has a question(text) and 4 images(imageButton), when user select the correct image, then they go to next question. So from question to question, should I:

1. call setContentView() multiple times in one activity? (layout is same for all questions, only the question text and image changes)
2. or add multiple layout in xml, and at runtime, set visibility of each layout? (but by doing so, I received warnings of too many views in one xml file)
3. any other better suggestions?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion populate the question dynamically...

From your Perspective do like this

1.Take xml with Question text and 4 images.
2. Get the Ids of question text(TextView), and 4 imageview's.
3.When ever the event trigger(i.e next question) change the question text and Answer images..

Try this simple logic

```
   int question=0;
ImageView answer1,answer2,answe3,answer4;
int answerids[]={R.id.answer1,R.id.answer1,R.id.answer1,R.id.answer1};
ImageView[] answerimages={answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4};
String questions[]={"Question1","Question2","...."};
int images[][]={{R.drawable.answer1,R.drawable.answer2,R.drawable.answer3,R.drawable.answer4},{second question drawables},{Third question drawables}...};
```

In onCreate do like this

```
TextView question=findViewById(R.id.question);
    for(int i=0;i<answerids.length;i++)
    {
        answerimages[i]=(ImageView)findViewById(answerids[i]);
        answerimages[i].setImageResource(images[question][i]);
        answerimages[i].setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                question+=1;
            nextqueston();

            }
        });
```

To populate next question text and images..

```
 public void nextqueston()
        {
            question.setText(questions[queston]);
            for(int i=0;i<answerids.length;i++)
            {
                answerimages[i].setImageResource(images[question][i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
So when I call setContentView(R.id.game), this game.xml at this point, should have question1's text and images only? where should I store the rest of the images? now I am fancying problems of:

a. store resources into game.xml, but I receive warning of too many views
b. store resources into separate xml file, but setContentView(R.id.game) wouldn't point to that xml, hence I have null pointer exception for ids that could not be found.

Comment: Hi Pragnani,

Thanks a lot for code! it is very clear to follow, now my app runs perfectly!! I think the key is to use "R.drawble…" to obtain a list of images, rather than "R.id…" , so to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the same Activity open, when one question is done, set the question text on the TextView programmatically, same for the ImageViews. All in the same layout.

Comment: But if I add all images into one layout.xml file, I receive "warnings of too many views", but if I add questions into several layout.xml file, i.e. question1.xml, question2.xml, and <include> them in my game.xml, when I call game.class and setContentView (R.id.game.xml), I then receive "null pointer exception" for find id by view.

Comment: You don't put all the images in one XML layout file. You need 4 images, so put 4 ImageViews in your layout. When you need to replace them, you do mImageView.setImage() and replace the 4 images with other 4 images (programmatically == in your code).